# WSO2-how to pass two parameters at a time with WSO2 ESB configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created a API in API manager. I can invoke it with

```
http://localhost:6547/generatereports/1.0/Reports/dcuid/vcid
```

I am passing two parameters with "dcuid and vcid" at a time  but not passing.

reportsapi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="generatereports/1.0/Reports" name="reportsdataapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" uri-template="/{dcuid}/{vcid}">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="http" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="404"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="reportsendpoint"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                    <send/>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>

            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>

            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

wso2 configuration process with to send the response is other than 200 response code
reportsendpoint:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="reporsendpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:6547/generatereports/1.0/Reports/{uri.var.dcuid}/{uri.var.vcid}"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Can you please explain "but not passing" part?

Comment: http://localhost:6547/generatereports/1.0/Reports/dcuid/vcid this urls configuraterate.passing dynamic with dcuid and vcid if you have any process with to send the response is other than 200 response code @ Bee

Comment: Sorry, still not clear.

Comment: this service url working fine getting data to send the response 200 if you have service not working or any internal server error to send the mail another response with client @Bee

Comment: ok. so you want to send a different response (or log?) if the status code is not 200? If the answer is yes, what's the title of the question about?

Comment: yes status code is  other than 200 response to send the mail content with service is  not working and status  code 404 or 400 or 500 any response

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to send a mail if the status code is other than 200. Then you can use [mailto transport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/MailTo+Transport) or mail connectors such as [gmail connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Gmail+Connector) [outlook connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Outlook+Mail+Connector) and add the configuration in the default section in the configured switch mediator.